# Removing tuple from nested list with tuple and lists

Tags: list, nested, tuples

I have a nested output in the form of this:

```
[(3, [['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '572.9964086553654'], ['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '34.858670832934195'], 
['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '22.09531308137768']])]
```

And I want to get rid of the int (3) which is in a tuple, and save the lists containing strings and ints.

How do I accomplish this in the best way?

My goal is to use the lists within the tuple for creating a dictionary later on, but while these ints are there within the tuple I don't know what to do. Basically I think I want an output such as:

```
[([['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '572.9964086553654'], ['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '34.858670832934195'], 
['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '22.09531308137768']])]
```

Comment: You mean this: `my_list[0] = my_list[0][1:]`? What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to store all of the lists, because my plan is to turn those lists within the tuple into a dictionary later, but currently my ints inside of the tuple hinders me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is enough:

```py
>>> value = [(3, [['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', ...
>>> value[0] = value[0][1:]
>>> value
    [([['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '572.9964086553654'], ['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '34.858670832934195'], ['Avg_Order_Insert_Size', '22.09531308137768']],)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!